# Which Method invoked whenever the marker is detected in MetaIO SDK

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am newbie to Augmented Reality(AR)

I am using the MetaIO SDK with unity, I am planning to play animation when the model is loaded.
Basically my idea is to have the animation played whenever the metaioman is set to be active. I've searched in google and unable to get some help.

Please guide me to have the animation played whenever the 3D object is seen

Thank you